# Any type of Rebel support available?

Tags: just-cause-3

I find some of the missions in military bases quite hard. Apart from getting a Rebel Drop, is there any other way to call the Rebels for help?

Comment: I can't answer your question, but my strategy was to try and hack any SAMs first, then get destructive. The game only resets soldiers and vehicles (not destroyed chaos objects or hacked SAMs), so you can chip away between respawns. Once all chaos objects are gone, the enemies despawn.

Comment: Ah, so you can hack SAMs. I destroy them but they respawn after my death, making get rid of them a Sysyphean task. Your suggestion is very useful.

Comment: Any _hacked_ SAM doesn't respawn, but any _destroyed_ SAM will respawn as an enemy SAM.  I've found that by _far_ the easiest way to take out a base is with a tank (even the lowliest one is awesome).  They're mostly immune to small arms fire, and there aren't any ant-tank defenses in a base (unlike SAMs vs. helicopters).  It's a bit less dramatic than some other ways of liberating a base, but I've found it to be by far the easiest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While liberating a base big enough, Annika might tell you that she is sending in rebel support. She will tell you to do a task, like hack all the SAMs for air support. You cannot call in rebels, but she will usually offer this support for big bases once you destroy about 1 to 2/4ths of a base. The rebels won't destroy chaos objects, but they will attack any form of militia, giving you cover.